# SQL CE Private Deployment & Out of Browser Silverlight

Tags: sql, silverlight-4.0, sql-server-ce

With Silverlight 4 we get access to COM and with SQL CE 4.0 we get Entity Framework and nice little database server.  I have a need for a standalone application (executing from a external jump drive) on a Windows machine without having to install any software. The requirement is that we cannot install any software on the target machine.

My thoughts are to develop a Silverlight out of the browser application, with SQL CE binaries included (not clear on how to accomplish) and run the application from the jump drive.

Does the solution make sense?

I found some pretty good information from the following MSDN link [MSDN Private vs Central deployment for SQL CE](http://silverlightcom.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) and from Erik Ejlkov blog [Everything SQL Server Compact](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/access-local-sql-compact-database-from.html) which is really good, however the solution assumes that SQL CE is installed on the local machine.

Thanks

Comment: After some research it would seem that SL4 does not have ADO client. So direct access to SQL CE would not be possible.